# CSS Sprite - is there a possible short way?

Tags: html, css

*E.g. I hava a 3 diffrent image as a sprite with hover.*

[image: e.g. for sprite]

```
<div class="sprite normal"></div>
```

*i dont want this type!*

```
/* small */
    .small{ width:20px; height:20px; }
    .small .sprite{ background:url(sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
    .small .sprite:hover { background:url(sprite.png) 20px 0 no-repeat; }
/* normal*/
    .normal{ width:50px; height:50px; }
    .normal .sprite{ background:url(sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
    .normal .sprite:hover { background:url(sprite.png) 50px 0 no-repeat; }
/* big */
    .big{ width:100px; height:100px; }
    .big .sprite{ background:url(sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
    .big .sprite:hover { background:url(sprite.png) 100px 0 no-repeat; }
```

is there a short way? thank you..

Comment: Seems pretty short and organized to me. I'd love to see if anyone has suggestions on how to make it shorter. +1

Comment: i can make this with jquery but i wonder, is there in css..

Comment: Yes, it's a good question, but I think it's quite organized, if you also apply the change that Amit Ranjan posted as an answer.

Comment: @avalkab could you please explain _why_ you want less css? I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't suffice but you obviously seem to think there is a reason to have even less of it.

Comment: Because of i wonder which is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sprite { background: url('sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat; }

.small { width: 20px; height: 20px; }
.small:hover { background-position: 20px 0; }

.normal { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
.normal:hover { backgorund-position: 50px 0; }

.big { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.big:hover { background-position: 100px 0 }
```

These are definitely all required styles, you're not going to achieve your goal with less rules.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about the last hover @insertusernamehere, but I'm wondering if the original css wasn't already faulty, as both classes are on the same element.

Comment: @avalkab why do you need shorter css? Maybe if you could explain that we could five a more thorough answer

Comment: Oh you're right about the classes being on the same element. I didn't take a look at the actual HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sprite{ background:url(sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }

/* small */
    .small{ width:20px; height:20px; }
    .small .sprite:hover { background:url(sprite.png) 20px 0 no-repeat; }

/* normal*/
    .normal{ width:50px; height:50px; }
    .normal .sprite:hover { background:url(sprite.png) 50px 0 no-repeat; }

/* big */
    .big{ width:100px; height:100px; }
    .big .sprite:hover { background:url(sprite.png) 100px 0 no-repeat; }
```

Comment: noo... this is same with shared my code. more short way? is possible? e.g. auto perception?...

Comment: No need to write the value for background-image and background-repeat several times – if you were to just use background-position in the specific rules.